# d3.v4.js weird dragging behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following these tutorials:

```
http://www.puzzlr.org/force-graphs-with-d3/ (for the basics)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amqrWq?editors=0010 (to add new circles dynamically)

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708 (for the zoom beha)
```

and I manage to create this:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/8qvx7mke/
```

but the drag functions are **flickering** the circle.

While the puzzlr.org example use

```
d.fx = d3.event.x;
d.fy = d3.event.y;
```

and in the animation

```
d3_nodes.attr('transform', function(d) {
    d.x = Math.max(d.r, Math.min(svg_width  - d.r, d.x));
    d.y = Math.max(d.r, Math.min(svg_height - d.r, d.y));
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
});
```

(although d.fx and d.fy aren't used anywhere else in the code...)

the bl.ocks.org example use:

```
d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
```

It looks like the circle is being positioned **twice** when dragging, but I couldn't find why.

If you could explain why one uses d.x and d.y, while the other uses d.fx and d.fy that would be great.

PS: if you replace this section:

```
var node_enter = d3_nodes.enter().append('g');

node_enter.append('text').text(function(d) {
    return 'naba naba ' + d.id;
});

node_enter
    .append('circle')
```

with this:

```
var node_enter = d3_nodes
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
```

it works! (But that leaves me with no < g> wrapping the < circle> and the < text>, and no < text> also, and I would like to have it this way).